# Magento - How to restrict customer can buy only one product for specific category

Tags: magento2, php, category, customer

I am trying to add free product for specific category, Customer can add only one free product in the cart for specific category. I tried to add shopping cart price rule as

Condition: If total quantity  less than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    Category  is  5

Action: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Category  is  5

But it doesn't work.

And I tried another way by custom coding:
get total items by category, if it is greater than count of 1, show haserror message in cart page. 
This also not working, I don't know exactly where to put this calculation.

Any idea?
Help me.

Comment: Can you post the related code ?

Comment: @AvijitGupta: I write a custom code to find out total products in the specific category; Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php      Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds('5'))->getName(); like this, I got the category name by loop,

Comment: Exactly what I need: Only one product customer can add in the cart. I want to write code to relate this, so if i get the total count of item in the category, i can restrict with error :  if ($totalItemByCategory>1) {
            $result->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(
                    Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('You cannot add one more free item in the cart.', '')
                )
                ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
            return $result;
        }

Comment: You can simply write event observer for check cart have 1 product from specific category?

Answer (score 0):

Magento default didn't provide for free product in Shopping Cart Price Rules. You need to find a plug-in for this.

[Here](http://www.extensions.sashas.org/coupon-gift-product.html) cheapest one that I used before.

This one is compatible up to Magento 1.9.2

Then, you can set free product based on which categories.

[image]

Comment: I added the category too, it doesn't work, if I want to edit code, which page should I edit?

Comment: @Lavanya Do you already install this plug-in?

Comment: No. Its not free plugin, suggest me free plugin.

Comment: But we have Shpping cart price rule option in magento itself. I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Lavanya I'm already find out free plug-in for this. I cannot fin out any other one. All are not free. Paid version :(

Comment: no need plug-in, megento has Shopping Cart Price rules option in Promotion tab already, we just need to know how to use it, otherwise need to customize the cart page.

Comment: If you cannot provide your customized code, we can only help for this way. Then, stackoverflow cannot provide complete solution.